# Unable to start Windows explorer = The procedure entry point memcpy_s could not be located in the dynamic library msvcrt.dll

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, system-restore

I keep getting the error

> Explorer.exe - Entry point not found
>
> The procedure entry point memcpy_s could not be located in the dynamic
>   library msvcrt.dll

Whenever I log-in to Windows XP. Explorer does not start, but throws this error. I am able to open task manager, but if I start explorer(or any other application) from the Task Manager, the same error keeps occurring

I found in some articles, that this may happen due to the fact that the msvcrt.dll file might have been changed from what was originally installed. 
I don't have my XP CD, so retrieving the original is not possible.

I am unable to run system restore because when I run rstrui.exe from command prompt, the same error popups with the title "rstrui.exe - Entry Point not found"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you run a System Restore?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The same error pops up with a different title : rstrui.exe - Entry Point not found"

Comment: Microsoft support has something you could try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324762

Comment: I did come across that. But as I mentioned ,I do not have my XP cd..

Comment: Aah, ok. Not sure what else you could do. Did you install something recently, which could have caused the error?

Comment: Ironically, this happened after I ran a diskcheck on C drive. Before that it was working well :-/
Never mind though, thanks for the help.
I think as a last resort, I will just resintall the entire OS somehow

Comment: If you could find a windows XP .iso you could easily re-install XP. There are a number of programs (e.g. ProduKey) that can extract your XP CD key.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably do that.

Comment: have you tried **sfc /scannow**?